# How to remove PayPal Credit and add Debit or Credit button using PayPal JS?

Tags: paypal

With the below code, along with the PayPal button a "PayPal Credit" button is shown. But I want to display Debit or Credit card black button instead of that PayPal Credit button. Please help me to find out the solution. I don't want to change anything in script tag, is there any change to be made?

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
    <!-- PayPal Shortcut Checkout -->
        <div id="paypalCheckoutContainer"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

//Javascript

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  paypal.Button.render({
            // Set your environment
            env: '<?= PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT ?>',

            // Set style of buttons
            style: {
                layout: 'vertical',   // horizontal | vertical
                size:   'medium',   // medium | large | responsive
                shape:  'pill',         // pill | rect
                color:  'gold',         // gold | blue | silver | black,
                fundingicons: false,    // true | false,
                tagline: false,          // true | false,
            },
       // Set allowed funding sources
            funding: {
                allowed: [
                    paypal.FUNDING.CARD,
                    paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT
                ],
                disallowed: [ ]
            },

            // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
            commit: false,
          // payment() is called to start the payment flow when a button is clicked
            payment: function() {
                const postData = {
                    'original': JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($orderDetails) ?>'),
                    'update': null,
                    'flow': 'shortcut'
                };
                return request.post(
                    '<?= $rootPath.URL['services']['orders']['create'] ?>',
                    postData
                ).then(function(returnObject) {
                    return returnObject.data.id;
                });
            },

            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data) {
                const postData = {
                    key: "order_id",
                    value: data.orderID
                };
                submitForm('<?= $baseUrl.URL['redirect']['orders']['return_url'] ?>?flow=shortcut', postData);
            },
// onCancel() is called when the buyer cancels payment authorization
            onCancel: function(data) {
                let url = "<?= $baseUrl ?>pages/orders/error?type=error",
                    postData = {
                        key: "error",
                        value: data
                    };
                submitForm(url, postData);
            },

            // onError() is called when there is an error in this Checkout.js script
            onError: function (error) {
                let url = "<?= $baseUrl ?>pages/orders/error?type=error",
                    postData = {
                        key: "error",
                        value: error
                    };
                submitForm(url, postData);
            }

        }, '#paypalCheckoutContainer');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the old "v4" checkout.js ([old demo site](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout-v4/#/pattern/vertical)). Upgrade to a [current PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) (which uses the "v5" JS SDK), and the black button will be available.

Since you appear to be using a backend for initial payment/order creation and later execution/capture , this front-end approval code has the best sample to work from: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

Since you ask about disabling the PayPal Credit button, for v5 the simplest way is to add `&disable-funding=credit` on the SDK src line